# aspell installs too many languages

Tags: locale, spell-checking, aspell

I have installed `aspell-en` and `aspell-de`. I have expected this will give me the choice between `en` and `de` languages. However, the package has installed many versions of `en` and `de` languages and now when I want to select my spell language, I get too many to choose from.

- Is it possible to configure somewhere, which languages are offered/displayed?
- Can I limit the list to, lets say only `en_US` and `de_CH` ?

I am sure I will never need `de_LI` and besides, I don't see any reason why `de_LI` should be a separate language anyway.

I am using Debian Wheezy.

[image: Available languages]

Comment: Deleting files from system directories is a very bad idea. This can break your system (probably not here), break upgrades, and changes will be overridden by the upgrade (or reinstallation) of the packages. The usual solution is to move the config to the user's home directory (or under `/usr/local`, depending on the context).

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to change the `data-dir` directory to one of your own, say `/path/to/lib/aspell`. Create (or modify) the file `~/.aspell.conf` with:

```
data-dir /path/to/lib/aspell
```

Then do the following:

```
mkdir /path/to/lib/aspell
cd /path/to/lib/aspell
ln -s /usr/lib/aspell/* .
rm *.alias *.multi
```

Then for the dictionaries you want, add .multi files based on what is in `/usr/lib/aspell` (recurse on the .multi files and include the .rws ones). For instance, in my case, `en.multi` contains:

```
add en-common.rws
add en-wo_accents-only.rws
```

and `fr_FR.multi` contains:

```
add fr-40-only.rws
add fr-60-only.rws
```

And I have only 2 dictionaries:

```
$ aspell dicts
en
fr_FR
```

instead of the 48 that are installed.

Tested on a Debian/unstable machine. I don't know whether there are better solutions...